# Multiple Pixel Shuffling

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have in issue with a piece of code in MATLAB as show below

```
Image = imread('fruit.jpg')
disp(Image);
N = size(Image);
    for i= (1:N)
      for j = (1:N)    
       l = rem((i + j),100) + 1;
       m = rem((i + 2*j),100) + 1;
       New_Array1(l,m) = Image(i,j);
      end;
    end;
```

Now I want the two statements in the for loop to be executed twice. For instance, initially the value of i & j = 1, After executing the two statements in the for loop l=3, m=4. But I want the new values to be assigned to i & j, as i=3, j=4. And the statement will again execute. with new values, 8 & 12. Now these values will be assigned to l & m after two iterations.

Comment: Could you please explain the motivation for this? It seems to me that your difficulties stem first and foremost from a flawed approach to a larger problem; the non-working code is only a symptom...

Comment: Actually I have to do the same code manually. Please check the link.
    http://goo.gl/mGesrM